NPN and PNP transistors for push pull amplifier
I always see that the NPN transistor is used in handling the positive signal while PNP transistor handling the negative signal in a push pull amplifier. What is the theory behind it? Can we swap the position of NPN and PNP? What will happen?

Simulate and find out?

Here is a pretty good tutorial that covers both analog and digital stages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_output

Short answer
If you "swap the position between npn and pnp" (joined with emitters) in a complementary emitter follower so that collectors are joined, it will become a complementary amplifier stage with dynamic load (like CMOS).
Of course, the bases must be properly managed (they cannot be simply joined as in CMOS).
Assembling complementary emitter follower
NPN emitter follower

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

PNP emitter follower

simulate this circuit

Complementary emitter follower

simulate this circuit

Assembling complementary CE amplifier stage
PNP CE amplifier stage

simulate this circuit

NPN CE amplifier stage

simulate this circuit

Complementary CE amplifier stage...

simulate this circuit

... with emitter resistors

simulate this circuit


The second circuit doesn’t work so well without some kind of negative feedback.

@hacktastical, that's how  should be, but it's strange why its gain is not higher than the simple CE amplifier with a collector resistor above.  Maybe I need to change the value of the bias voltages of the two transistors. There is also another problem - there is no current-limiting resistor in the string formed from the two diodes and the two base-emitter junctions. So I inserted 10 ohm resistors in the emitters. In general, my purpose is to show the principle, and therefore I do not want to digress into details.

This is a NPN transistor, as it would be used in a push-pull amplifier. It's the part responsible for dealing with signals that are positive, greater than zero:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here are the input (blue) and output (orange) voltages, as the change with time:

As you can see, it does a good job of imposing the same voltage across the loudspeaker as it "sees" at its base, but only for the positive half of the input cycle.
The voltages are nearly identical (during the positive parts), so it has a voltage gain of nearly 1.
Putting a PNP in its place, we have this:

simulate this circuit
Behaviour changes completely:

The voltage applied to the speaker doesn't change at all, and is permanently stuck near the supply of +15V. This is likely to kill the transistor and loudspeaker quite quickly.
There are many reasons for this difference in behaviour, to do with voltage polarities, current direction and load placement/configuration, but they are too many and too complex for a quick answer on Stack Exchange.
If you want to understand, you should study the topics "common-emitter" and "common-collector" (otherwise known as emitter-follower"). Wikipedia also has articles: Common Emitter, Common Collector.
Be warned though, if you don't first have a firm grasp on the fundamentals like Kirchhoff's Voltage Law and Kirchhoff's Current Law, and are not very comfortable with resistors and diodes too, those articles are going to be a tough read.

The simplest way to configure BJTs as a push-pull amplifier is to have the NPN on the high side, and the PNP on the low side thus:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this configuration, each transistor is configured as an emitter follower. That is, for each transistor, the emitter voltage (more or less) tracks the base voltage offset by a (nearly constant) base-emitter voltage. Although biasing the bases in such a configuration is not trivial, it is fairly straightforward. Finding an appropriate balance between the conflicting goals of minimizing quiescent emitter current, and minimizing cross-over distortion is usually the main task.
If one were to simply swap the PNP and NPN transistors as below, properly biasing the bases is not quite so simple.

simulate this circuit
Now, each base should be biased to approximately 0.7 V offset from V+ or V- as appropriate. However, controlling the collector voltages will be problematic with this simple setup, but controlling the collector voltages is precisely what is wanted for a reasonable amplifier.
The above simple scheme isn't practical. However, with feedback, a practical amplifier can be constructed with the drive transistors collector-to-collector. The simplest way to get the appropriate feedback is to use Sziklai pairs thus:

simulate this circuit
In this configuration, the bases of Q3 and Q4 are driven (more or less) identically to how one would drive a standard emitter-follower push-pull amplifier. However, the final drive transistors are connected collector-to-collector. Although Q1 and Q2 provide the bulk of the output current, they are "weaker" than Q3 and Q4 in determining the output voltage. If Q1 and Q2 should "attempt" to cause the output voltage to drift away from what Q3 and Q4 want to set the output voltage, that "drift", will result in changes to the emitter voltages of Q3 and Q4, which in turn will cause corrective changes to the collector voltages of Q3 and Q4, and thus to the bases of Q1 and Q2. It is an "odd" sort of feedback, but it works.

Of all the answers, this is the only one that 'gets' it. Negative feedback is essential for the common-emitter devices to work as a linear amplifier, and the Sziklai pair is an elegant way to do it. +1

The NPN is an emitter follower for positive voltages and the PNP is an emitter follower for the negative volages.
You can't simply exchange them.
If you simply exchange the transistors, and assuming the pinout for C/B/E terminals match, they will be both on at the same time, pass a lot of current, and something will blow up, burn up, melt, or damage (power supply fuses, the transistors, PCB, or the circuit driving the transistors.
